# Is it possible to count vertices with only two connected edges without bmesh?

Tags: python, objects, bmesh

Is it possible to count the number of vertices of only two connected edges without `bmesh`? Like with object data we can count triangles

```
        for loop in obj.data.polygons:
            count = loop.loop_total

            if count == 3:
                tris += 1
```

`bmesh` eat much resources because the script monitor statistic in realtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to count the number of verts that belong to exactly two edges? You can first count how many edges each vert belongs to, then count how many of those counts were 2.

```
vert_edge_counts = [0] * len(obj.data.vertices)

for edge in obj.data.edges:
    for v in edge.vertices:
        vert_edge_counts[v] += 1
        
num_verts_with_two_edges = sum(
    count == 2 for count in vert_edge_counts
)
```

Comment: Blimey. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a faster version. I tested this on a model with 160k vertices and it was faster by up to 50%.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

obj = bpy.context.object
seq = np.array([0] * len(obj.data.edges) * 2, dtype=np.int32)
obj.data.edges.foreach_get("vertices", seq)
unique_values, counts = np.unique(seq, return_counts=True)
num_verts_with_two_edges = sum(count // 2 for count in counts if count == 2)
```

Comment: is it possible to optimize if I need multiple values "count == 0, 1, 2" (to not duplicate whole expression) ?

Comment: @APEC you can do `if count in [0,1,2]` or more efficient `if count <= 2`